# Difficulty accessing information in api's returned json array. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I am trying to get information out of a json response from the weather.gov api (https://api.weather.gov/). There's a good chance that I'm overthinking my problem, because I am getting the expected number of responses, but all 2,748 of those responses are 'undefined'.

I've tried accessing the properties that I have seen in the json object response via dot notation, I have tried .map and .forEach methods to possibly try to get a different output, and I have read several dozen blog posts that seem to deal with "simpler" api's. I have also read several posts here on SO, but I have not been able to understand what's wrong.

I'm pretty sure at this point that my mistake is small, but I can't see it.

```
const endpoint = 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/';

async function getStations() {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    const data = await response.json();

    stationInfo = data.observationStations;
    // data.observationStations.forEach(function(e) {
    //     console.log(e.properties);
    // });

    for(let i in stationInfo) {
        // ext = stationInfo[i].slice(-4);
        // console.log(endpoint + ext);
        console.log(stationInfo[i].id)
    }
}

getStations();
```

here is an example of the json that I'm trying to work with

```
{
    "@context": [
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geojson/geojson-ld/master/contexts/geojson-base.jsonld",
        {
            "wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#",
            "s": "https://schema.org/",
            "geo": "http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#",
            "unit": "http://codes.wmo.int/common/unit/",
            "@vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#",
            "geometry": {
                "@id": "s:GeoCoordinates",
                "@type": "geo:wktLiteral"
            },
            "city": "s:addressLocality",
            "state": "s:addressRegion",
            "distance": {
                "@id": "s:Distance",
                "@type": "s:QuantitativeValue"
            },
            "bearing": {
                "@type": "s:QuantitativeValue"
            },
            "value": {
                "@id": "s:value"
            },
            "unitCode": {
                "@id": "s:unitCode",
                "@type": "@id"
            },
            "forecastOffice": {
                "@type": "@id"
            },
            "forecastGridData": {
                "@type": "@id"
            },
            "publicZone": {
                "@type": "@id"
            },
            "county": {
                "@type": "@id"
            }
        }
    ],
    "id": "https://api.weather.gov/stations/KVBS",
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -93.629999999999995,
            29.48
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "@id": "https://api.weather.gov/stations/KVBS",
        "@type": "wx:ObservationStation",
        "elevation": {
            "value": 68.275199999999998,
            "unitCode": "unit:m"
        },
        "stationIdentifier": "KVBS",
        "name": "SABINE 13B OIL PLATFORM",
        "timeZone": "America/Chicago",
        "forecast": "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/GMZ450"
    }
}
```

Since I was successful in getting the url's for each item in the json array, I expected to be able to access the properties of those items also - instead, I'm getting 'undefined'. However as I said earlier, I'm getting 'undefined' the expected number of times.

Comment: It's an array that I can see in console.log(data). Is forEach more efficient?

Comment: You first need to make a GET request via an HTTP service.

Comment: @Michael he is. That is what fetch does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping the observationStations you just need a simple forEach

```js
const endpoint = 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/';

const getStations = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    const data = await response.json();    
    data.observationStations.forEach(station => console.log(station) )
}

getStations();
```

HOWEVER You likely want to access the features object array:

```js
const endpoint = 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/';

const getStations = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(endpoint);
  const data = await response.json();
  const list = data.features.map(feat =>
    `<dt>${feat.properties.stationIdentifier}</dt>
     <dd><a href="${feat.id}">${feat.properties.name}</a></dd>`
  )
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = list.join('');
}

getStations();
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none
}

dl {
  border: 3px double #ccc;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 70px;
  /* text-align: right; */
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: pre;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}

dt::after {
  content: ":";
}

dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0 0 0.1em 0;
}
```

```html
<dl id="list"></dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

the point is that `observationStations` attribute object obtained from `https://api.weather.gov/stations/` is an array of strings not objects.

Therefore to print the string you should do:

```js
console.log(stationInfo[i])
```

instead of:

```js
console.log(stationInfo[i].id)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Oh geez. Yeah, I'm in business now. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try something like:

```js
const endpoint = 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/';

const getStations = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    const data = await response.json();    
    data.observationStations.forEach(item => console.log(item));  
}

getStations();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `observationStations`:

```js
const endpoint = 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/';

async function getStations() {
    console.log('calling');
    const data = await fetch(endpoint).then(res => res.json());
    
    const observationStations = data.observationStations;

    observationStations.forEach(observationStation => console.log(observationStation));
    
}

getStations();
```

But just an NB I don't think you should make this kind of calls ( retrieving all the stations at once). Maybe there is a much better call which takes much less time from the API.